# SOAP UI throws connection exception for WCF Entity Framework project

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework-6, wcf-binding

I have added all my code below. This code is taken from Microsoft CRUD tutorial and I am trying to adopt these services to WCF project.

In the WCF service implementation, I have a `FindStudent()` method. If I comment out the second line of the code which starts with `db.Entry`, it works and I am getting a response.

My requirement is to populate the return `Student` object for this method with all information of the record along with navigational property enrollments. When I try to use this second line SOAP UI is throwing an error

> ERROR:java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Please help.

```
public Student FindStudent(int? id)
{
    var student = db.Students.Find(id);
    //db.Entry(student).Collection(s => s.Enrollments).Load(); 
    return student;
}
```

Below is the response when the second line is commented out, `Enrollments` is NULL. But I need this field to be populated. How to achieve this?

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <FindStudentResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <FindStudentResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfServiceApp.Models" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:EnrollmentDate>2005-09-01T00:00:00</a:EnrollmentDate>
            <a:Enrollments i:nil="true"/>
            <a:FirstMidName>RaviTeja</a:FirstMidName>
            <a:ID>1</a:ID>
            <a:LastName>Sunkavalli</a:LastName>
         </FindStudentResult>
      </FindStudentResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Model classes:

```
namespace WcfServiceApp.Models
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Student
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
        //public string emailAddress { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Course
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [DataMember]
        public int CourseID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Credits { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public enum Grade
    {
        A, B, C, D, F
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Enrollment
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int EnrollmentID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int CourseID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public Grade? Grade { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public Course Course { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public Student Student { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class EnrollmentDateGroup
    {
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime? EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int StudentCount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Below is the WCF interface and service:

```
namespace WcfServiceApp
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<EnrollmentDateGroup> GetStudentForHome();

        [OperationContract]
        IEnumerable<Student> GetStudents();

        [OperationContract]
        Student FindStudent(int? id);

        [OperationContract]
        Boolean SaveStudent(Student student);

        [OperationContract]
        Boolean DeleteStudent(int id);
    }
}
```

Implementation:

```
namespace WcfServiceApp
{
    public class MyService : IMyService
    {
        private SchoolContext db = new SchoolContext();

        public List<EnrollmentDateGroup> GetStudentForHome()
        {
            IQueryable<EnrollmentDateGroup> data = from student in db.Students
                                                   group student by student.EnrollmentDate into dateGroup
                                                   select new EnrollmentDateGroup()
                                                              { 
                                                                  EnrollmentDate = dateGroup.Key,
                                                                  StudentCount = dateGroup.Count()
                                                              };
            return data.ToList();
        }

        public IEnumerable<Student> GetStudents()
        {
            var students =  from s in db.Students select s;
            // db.Entry(student).Reference(s=>s.Enrollments).L
            //return students.ToList();
            return students;
        }

        public Student FindStudent(int? id)
        {
            var student = db.Students.Find(id);
            //db.Entry(student).Collection(s => s.Enrollments).Load();  -->Without this line I get //response but that property in return response from service is null. I want this property list in my //response. How to do that?
            return student;
        }

        public Boolean SaveStudent(Student student)
        {
            db.Students.Add(student);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }

        public Boolean DeleteStudent(int id)
        {
            Student student = db.Students.Find(id);
            db.Students.Remove(student);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my `DbContext` class, I am using EF6 and initializer.

```
namespace WcfServiceApp.DAL
{
    public class SchoolContext : DbContext
    {
        public SchoolContext() : base("SchoolContext")
        {
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            Console.WriteLine("called school context constructor");
        }

        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }

    public class SchoolInitializer: System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<SchoolContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(SchoolContext context)
        {
            var students = new List<Student>
            {
            new Student{FirstMidName="RaviTeja",LastName="Sunkavalli",EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2005-09-01")},
            new Student{FirstMidName="SaiKrishna",LastName="Nadimpalli",EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2002-09-01")},
            new Student{FirstMidName="SudeepReddy",LastName="Panyam",EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2003-09-01")},
            new Student{FirstMidName="Meha",LastName="Patel",EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2019-09-01")},
            new Student{FirstMidName="Venkatesh",LastName="Moturi",EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2019-09-01")},
            new Student{FirstMidName="Teja",LastName="Duggirala",EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2019-09-01")},
            new Student{FirstMidName="Ashwanth",LastName="Pullalakonda",EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2003-09-01")},
            new Student{FirstMidName="Himesh",LastName="Annam",EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2005-09-01")}
            };

            students.ForEach(s => context.Students.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();
            Console.WriteLine("saved student base data");

            var courses = new List<Course>
            {
            new Course{CourseID=1050,Title="Chemistry",Credits=3,},
            new Course{CourseID=4022,Title="Microeconomics",Credits=3,},
            new Course{CourseID=4041,Title="Macroeconomics",Credits=3,},
            new Course{CourseID=1045,Title="Calculus",Credits=4,},
            new Course{CourseID=3141,Title="Trigonometry",Credits=4,},
            new Course{CourseID=2021,Title="Composition",Credits=3,},
            new Course{CourseID=2042,Title="Literature",Credits=4,}
            };

            courses.ForEach(s => context.Courses.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var enrollments = new List<Enrollment>
            {
            new Enrollment{StudentID=1,CourseID=1050,Grade=Grade.A},
            new Enrollment{StudentID=1,CourseID=4022,Grade=Grade.C},
            new Enrollment{StudentID=1,CourseID=4041,Grade=Grade.B},
            new Enrollment{StudentID=2,CourseID=1045,Grade=Grade.B},
            new Enrollment{StudentID=2,CourseID=3141,Grade=Grade.F},
            new Enrollment{StudentID=2,CourseID=2021,Grade=Grade.F},
            new Enrollment{StudentID=3,CourseID=1050},
            new Enrollment{StudentID=4,CourseID=1050,},
            new Enrollment{StudentID=4,CourseID=4022,Grade=Grade.F},
            new Enrollment{StudentID=5,CourseID=4041,Grade=Grade.C},
            new Enrollment{StudentID=6,CourseID=1045},
            new Enrollment{StudentID=7,CourseID=3141,Grade=Grade.A},
            };

            enrollments.ForEach(s => context.Enrollments.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            Console.WriteLine("saved enrollments base data");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably a circular reference issue in the serializer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be Proxy Generation serialization problem. Try disabling proxy generation in your dbcontext. If the exception disappears then you can use DTOs or use [ProxyDataContractResolver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.proxydatacontractresolver?view=netframework-4.8).
How to configure [Custom Data Contract Resolver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-a-data-contract-resolver).